# How to order by a part of a column?

Tags: sql, mysql

I want to make an `order by` stuff using a part of some column.For example,some records of the column `user` look as below

```
vip1,vip2,vip21,vip10,vip100
```

If I do a `order by user`,the order would be

```
vip1,vip10,vip100,vip2,vip21
```

Then how can I make the result as follows

```
vip1,vip2,vip10,vip21,vip100
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What RDBMS?

For SQL Server to get numeric sorting rather than lexicographic sorting it would be something like

```
ORDER BY CAST(RIGHT(col, LEN(col)-3) AS INT)
```

For MySQL

```
ORDER BY CAST(RIGHT(col, LENGTH(col)-3) AS UNSIGNED)
```

but why are you storing the `vip` part at all if it is the same for all rows?

Comment: yeah that's a point.but tables are designed by others so little can do about it.:(

Answer (score 1):

You can also replace the user name ('vip') with nothing ('') and add zero, then sort.  Not any more efficient, just more generic.

Answer (score 1):

Is the "prefix" part always exactly 3 characters? If not, this gets complicated. Umm, with Postgres you could

```
order by regexp_matches(userid,"^[a-z]*")[1], substring(userid, regexp_matches(userid,"^[a-z]*")[1])::int
```

I think that would work,I haven't tried it. Anyway, the point is, if you have some function that will do regular expressions, you couild pull off a leading string of alphas, then peal off what's left and convert it to int.

If you're really embedding a number in an alpha field, a better alternative is: Don't do that. If this is two different logical data items, then make it two fields. It's a lot easier to put fields together than to take them apart.